# JSON object array is stored

Tags: php, laravel-8

The JSON object array is stored in the products table, need to do a query to retrieve certain objects using Laravel Query Builder. How would I retrieve the first object array, or certain parts of it? Table : products Field name : id, prodcatkey normal datatype Field name : “pricematrix” JSON data type [enter code here {“packing”:“1”,“size”:“500ml”,“vencode”:“1EIFEL”,“price”:“527.50”}, {“packing”:“3”,“size”:“500ml”,“vencode”:“1EIFEL”,“price”:“1582.50”}, {“packing”:“6”,“size”:“500ml”,“vencode”:“1EIFEL”,“price”:“3165.00”}, {“packing”:“12”,“size”:“500ml”,“vencode”:“1EIFEL”,“price”:“6330.00”} ]

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use normal Laravel query builder to find it.

```
$query->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(pricematrix->"$.packing",1)');
```

Or using

```
$query->whereJsonContains('pricematrix->packing', ['1', '2'])
```